# How to configure Maven to use HTTPS when connecting to repo.maven.apache.org

Tags: maven, https

I would like to secure the connection to `repo.maven.apache.org` when resolving dependencies (I wolud like to secure all connections made by Maven actually), but I'm not used to Maven configuration... My user `settings.xml` contains the following `repositories` and `pluginRepositories` sections:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>main</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

However Maven is unable to resolve dependencies with that setup.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open the file `$MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml` (where `$MAVEN_HOME` is the folder in which Maven has been installed) in a text editor.  Then, add the following to the `<mirrors>...</mirrors>` section in this file:

```
<mirror>
  <id>central-secure</id>
  <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```